# SSRS REST API - I Want to get all CatalogItems where Type = Report

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using Postman to test a GET on my SSRS database.  The GET is "http://server/reports/api/v2.0/CatalogItems".  This works and gives me lots of information.  One of the values is "Type": which has values such a "Folder" and "Report".  I would like to get only the Reports.  I can get a specific report using "http://server/reports/api/v2.0/CatalogItems?$filter=Name eq 'ReportXYZ'".  But if I use "?$filter=Type eq 'Report'" I get the error "The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Model.CatalogItemType' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'."

Any ideas how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

FINALLY found the answer!  "?$filter=Type eq Model.CatalogItemType'Report'".  I don't know why this isn't documented better on the Swagger site or one of Microsoft's pages.

Type is a enum, not a string.  So for any enum's this should work.